# How Customize Scaffolding MVC Controller in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I want to have a Template to build my MVC project controllers.

These controllers are CRUD type. Is it possible to use custom Scaffolding?

Can I Design and Run a Template for Scaffolding myself?

After searching and searching the internet, I found and searched for Scaffolding system files, but there was no VS2019 installation folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: tnq @Steve .Is it possible to create multiple files through T4 Templates?
For example controller.cs and index.cshtml, edit.cshtml, ...

Comment: I've only ever used them once years ago for a single template. I would say so though. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers/ is a good place to find out more. The article is 11 years old but it should still mostly stand.

Comment: Yes Marjid, there is very little relevant information on this topic. I'm still hunting high and low to learn exactly the same thing.